# How can you sort a const vector?

Tags: c++, vector

If I have a const vector defined in my class, how can I go about sorting it?

Attempting to sort a const vector will give errors since I'm changing the contents of a const vector.

Comment: Why is it const if you need to modify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't.  If you need to modify it... well then it shouldn't be `const`.  The two goals are in direct conflict with one another.

Instead of asking for a solution to a problem that doesn't make sense, tell us what you are actually trying to accomplish here.  Are you trying to return a vector from a method that you don't want the *caller* to be able to modify?  In that case, create a getter method and return a `const vector&`

```
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
public:
    // clients can't change this vector directly
    const std::vector<int>& get_vector() const { return _vec; }

    // you can still create an interface that allows 
    // mutation of the vector in a safe way, or mutate
    // the vector internally.
    void push_back( int i ) { _vec.push_back( i ); }
private:
    std::vector<int> _vec;
}
```

Comment: @Rob: Raymond Chen said it best:  [Before You Develop a Solution, Make Sure You Really Understand the Problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Is it the vector that's const?  Or the data inside it that needs to be const?

If you have a const vector, then there's probably a reason why it shouldn't be modified....

That being said.  Here's pseudocode on how you can shoot yourself in the foot:

```
const std::vector< Foo* > v;  // hypothetical declaration
std::vector< Foo* >* vPtr = const_cast< std::vector< Foo* >* >(&v);
// GOOD LUCK
(*vPtr)[0] = new Foo();
```

Comment: +1 for "here's how you can shoot yourself in the foot" comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can sort a const vector in C++.

Let a const vector is v.

```
const vector<int> v={5,4,3,2,1};
```

If you want to sort this vector using `sort(v.begin(),v.end())` then it will result some runtime error due to violation of const.

But Here is the magic-

```
vector<int>*temp=(vector<int>*)&v;
sort(temp->begin(),temp->end());
```

You can sort the vector v using another vector pointer and referencing it to that.

After this, if you print the vector v then you will get output like this -

```
for(int a:v)
    cout<<a<<" ";
cout<<endl;
```

Output: `1 2 3 4 5`

Comment: I would recommend against this in nearly all cases as this will lead to code that is hard to debug. Yes it can be done but marking something as a const is meant to be a contract. Other pieces of code will make assumptions based on it being constant. This will make bugs hard to debug and means everyone needs to understand all the code rather than abstracting away the implementation. It might not cause a bug today but down the line its sure to.